# UPDATE total count of status (PENDING, CONFIRMED, CANCELLED) according to user (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table, how can i update the total count of each status accordingly.

**CUSTOMER TABLE**

| CustomerID | COUNT1 | COUNT2 | COUNT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 202 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**ORDER TABLE**

| SID | CID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5013 | 201 | PENDING |
| 5014 | 201 | PENDING |
| 5015 | 202 | CONFIRMED |
| 5016 | 201 | CANCELLED |
| 5017 | 202 | PENDING |
| 5018 | 201 | CANCELLED |

**RESULT WILL BE THE FOLLOWING:**

```
COUNT1 (PENDING)
COUNT2 (CONFIRMED)
COUNT3 (CANCELLED)
```

| CID | COUNT1 | COUNT2 | COUNT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 202 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: Don't name your fields COUNT1, COUNT2, COUNT3, but COUNTPENDING, COUNTCONFIRMED, COUNTCANCELLED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT cid,
       SUM(status = 'PENDING') AS count1,
       SUM(status = 'CONFIRMED') AS count2,
       SUM(status = 'CANCELLED') AS count3
FROM `order`
GROUP BY 1
```

and accordingly

```
UPDATE customer
JOIN (
    SELECT cid,
           SUM(status = 'PENDING') AS count1,
           SUM(status = 'CONFIRMED') AS count2,
           SUM(status = 'CANCELLED') AS count3
    FROM `order`
    GROUP BY 1
    ) amounts USING (cid)
SET customer.count1 = amounts.count1, 
    customer.count2 = amounts.count2, 
    customer.count3 = amounts.count3
```